# Multipart request loses information on larger file uploads from IE 7/8

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, multipartform-data

I'm not sure if it happens in other browsers, because in other browsers, we're able to check the file size on the client side after the file is selected. We don't allow uploads larger than 2MB, so we will block the user from the UI side if they select a file too large.

But IE 7/8 apparently doesn't allow us to do this. So we'd like to detect this server side and send back the appropriate message. However, exceptions are thrown when we see that parts of the request are missing.

I can see the properties in my Fiddler request, so I know they're being sent:

```
-----------------------------7db16b332033c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="folderId"

CA15R1bH08ZxJ`DPL0mstwGjHMlrjKobu9VHBoPASniX8`UXgM8dnazjICvwfUj2qUKk14rh|NlB|uaUNkiVjPAqkX`kxWRl
-----------------------------7db16b332033c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="docGuid"


-----------------------------7db16b332033c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fromSharedTree"

false
```

However, the properties are not available when I execute the following code, so exceptions are thrown.

```
        string categoryId = request["folderId"];
        string docGuid = request["docGuid"];
        bool isUpdate = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(docGuid);
        bool isShared = bool.Parse(request["fromSharedTree"]);
```

Where did the values go? How do I get them back!?

**Edit**

Any attempt to access `Request.InputStream` results in an exception in this scenario. That would seem to be related. Who's imposing the size limit here? Is it .NET? IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server side here's how you handle uploaded file sizes:

```
foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in Request.Files)
{
    if (file.ContentLength > 2097152)
    {
        // ... this file is larger than 2 MB
    }
}
```

Also make sure that you have set a sufficiently large [maxRequestLength](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx) in your web.config (`<httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" />`) or the controller action might not be hit at all if the file is bigger than the allowed quota.

You might also find the [following article useful](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) for uploading files in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: `Request.Files` also throws an exception in this case. We don't have `maxRequestLength` defined in our `Web.config` but the endpoint is being hit so I wouldn't suspect that this is the issue.

Comment: Adding the `maxRequestLength` property and setting it to a large size solves the problem, but if you encounter a file size larger than this, you will always get exceptions when accessing properties from the request. Thanks for the tip!